# Set Status by checking if any value matches Lookup table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have 2 tables Test1 and Test2. If any 1 value of M_OFF,M_PREF,R_OFF,R_PREF matches with value in CODE column of Test2 Table, then set status as 'Yes', else set 'No'

**Test1 :**

```
ID | M_OFF | M_PREF | R_OFF | R_PREF
1  | H     | H      | M     | M
2  | H     | H      | L     | L
3  | L     | L      | L     | L
```

**Test2 :**

```
CODE

H
M
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ID | M_OFF | M_PREF | R_OFF | R_PREF | STATUS
1  | H     | H      | M     | M      | YES
2  | H     | H      | L     | L      | YES
3  | L     | L      | L     | L      | NO
```

Join both tables will give me duplicate values which is not expected. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from test2 t2 where t2.code in (t1.M_OFF, t1.M_PREF, t1.R_OFF, t1.R_PREF)
             then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end) as status
from test1 t1;
```

Comment: Yet again you are just too damn fast for me :-)

Comment: I think now `Fast` should change its name to Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query:

```
SELECT ID, M_OFF, M_PREF, R_OFF, R_PREF, 
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM Test2
           WHERE Code IN (M_OFF, M_PREF, R_OFF, R_PREF)
       ) THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END As [Status]
FROM Test1
```